# how to access arrays from different component in angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, search, components

I'm new to programming and just wondering how I can access arrays from a different component in angular project

This data   **`chips: Array<String> = ["One", "Two", "Three"];`**  are inside `tags.component.ts` file

I want to access those data inside `home.component.ts` file

I have search filter inside home component so I'm trying to access those data and to display inside home component when a user search for those data.

Thanks

Comment: If you need shared data one way is to use a singleton service to hold that data. The service can then be injected to components where you need the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that. Take a look at this material, you'll learn from this https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Long story short - there is a couple of ways to share data (via Input, via ViewChild, via Output() and EventEmitter) and sharing data between unrelated components with a Service.

I hope that will help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you won't get much of an answer because the answer is more involved than a simple do this. Also, they'll ding you with a negative vote for not posting a project link to what you have tried for them to see all the code you are working with.

My suggestion is that you watch this series on Angular 6. It is very in depth and very good.
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/1/